# Do we need to serialize the VAO and VBO

Tags: c++, opengl, serialization, boost

I am serializing my data using boost.

This is how my class looks like.

I  am serializing most of the data except the VAO , VBO and the shader.

My object gets deserialized correctly.

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "Geometry.h"
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include "shader.h"
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>



class Sum_Circle : public Geometry
{
public:
    Sum_Circle();
    Sum_Circle(const Shader& shader);
    Sum_Circle(const Sum_Circle& circle);
    Sum_Circle& operator=(const Sum_Circle& circle);
    ~Sum_Circle();
    Geometry* Clone() const;
    void init();
    void CleanUp();
    void draw();
    std::vector<float> GetMesh();
    std::vector<float> data;
    std::vector< Sum_Vertices > GetVertices();
    void CreateUI(QFormLayout* layout);

private:
    bool isInited;
    int iSegments;
    unsigned int m_VAO, m_VBO, m_EBO;
    int iNumsToDraw;
    bool isChanged;
    Shader shader;
    int iEntries;

public slots:
    void ParamChange();


private:
    typedef Geometry _Super;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<typename Archive>
    void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version ) const {

        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<_Super>(*this);
        ar & isInited & iSegments & m_VAO & m_VBO & m_EBO & iNumsToDraw & isChanged  & iEntries;
    }

    template<typename Archive>
    void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)  {

        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<_Super>(*this);
        ar & isInited & iSegments & m_VAO & m_VBO & m_EBO & iNumsToDraw & isChanged  & iEntries;
    }

    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()

};
```

This is how shader class looks like.

```
class Shader
{
public:
    // State
    GLuint ID;
    // Constructor
    Shader() { }
    // Sets the current shader as active
    Shader  &Use();
    // Compiles the shader from given source code
    void    Compile(const GLchar *vertexSource, const GLchar *fragmentSource, const GLchar *geometrySource = nullptr); // Note: geometry source code is optional 
    // Utility functions
    void    SetFloat(const GLchar *name, GLfloat value, GLboolean useShader = false);
    void    SetInteger(const GLchar *name, GLint value, GLboolean useShader = false);
    void    SetVector2f(const GLchar *name, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLboolean useShader = false);
    void    SetVector2f(const GLchar *name, const glm::vec2 &value, GLboolean useShader = false);
    void    SetVector3f(const GLchar *name, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z, GLboolean useShader = false);
    void    SetVector3f(const GLchar *name, const glm::vec3 &value, GLboolean useShader = false);
    void    SetVector4f(const GLchar *name, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z, GLfloat w, GLboolean useShader = false);
    void    SetVector4f(const GLchar *name, const glm::vec4 &value, GLboolean useShader = false);
    void    SetMatrix4(const GLchar *name, const glm::mat4 &matrix, GLboolean useShader = false);
private:
    // Checks if compilation or linking failed and if so, print the error logs
    void    checkCompileErrors(GLuint object, std::string type);
};
```

Do we need to serialize the VAO and the VBO  as currently I do not do this , but  the object still gets deserialized correctly.

Comment: Please include a [MCVE], showing how you serialize and deserialize. Thanks!

Comment: @Max Vollmer i have updated the code.

Comment: The V*O integers that are stored by your objects are handles into OpenGL memory. If you intend to use these in a different invocation of your program, you need to recreate them (`glGenVertexArray`, `glGenBuffers` and `glCreateShader`). This may have happened in your `Sum_Circle` constructor, but you did not show the code so we cannot answer the question for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by VAO you mean the one you get from glGenVertexArrays then 'No'.
You need to generate them on each run. These are OpenGL Id's. On each application run they can be different.